# How to store a SoapObject or Envelope in a File

Tags: java, android, serialization, ksoap2

I am trying to store `SoapObject` or `Envelope` in a file but thought it is not Serializable, it is not stored in file.

My goal is to store `SoapObject` or `Envelope` one time in file and next time instead of building a new `SoapObject` or `Envelope`, fetch that object from stored file.

I have created all the methods using [easywsdl.com](http://easywsdl.com) site. It has its custom `ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope` having following definition.

```
public class ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope extends
    SoapSerializationEnvelope
{
    //Envelop code
}
```

I make that envelope Serializable using following pattern.

```
public class ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope extends
    SoapSerializationEnvelope implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

And write using following code in file.

```
public static void writeEnvelope(Object object) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "envelope.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

It successfully write `Envelope` but when I tried to read that object from file using following code,

```
public static Object readEnvelope() throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "envelope.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```

it fires following exception,

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope; IllegalAccessException
```

Do any one has idea hot to achieve that? Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: can you get solution from this question?

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the way to save SoapObject to file and get it from file.

```
public boolean saveToFile(SoapObject temp) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "saveFile");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(temp);
    XmlSerializer aSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        aSerializer.setOutput(os, "UTF-8");
        envelope.write(aSerializer);
        aSerializer.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = _context.openFileOutput("response" + ".xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(bytes);
        oos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}


public SoapObject getFromFile() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "getFile");
    ObjectInputStream input;
    String filename = "response.xml";
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = _context.openFileInput(filename);
        input = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) input.readObject();
        input.close();
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        SoapObject soap = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            XmlPullParser p = Xml.newPullParser();
            p.setInput(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            envelope.parse(p);
            soap = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return soap;
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "StreamCorruptedException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "FileNotFoundException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "ClassNotFoundException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

It store in android app folder not in sdcard or phone storage

Answer (score 0):

Save SoapObject as XMl, sometimes parse it directly may cause out of memory.

```
public boolean saveToXML(SoapObject temp) {
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(temp);
XmlSerializer aSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    aSerializer.setOutput(os, "UTF-8");
    envelope.write(aSerializer);
    aSerializer.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = _context.openFileOutput("response" + ".xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(bytes);
    oos.close();
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```